# How can I shrink these areas using gimp?

Tags: gimp, images, png

I have an imagemap. I want to shrink to areas that are pink and are overlays when hovering the mouse over the map to highlight the selected region. Now I can't seem to shrink the pink areas that are used for highlighting the regions. If I press shrink then it seems like only a preview and the areas are not shrunk. I need a way to remove the areas that I want removed.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To scale a selection we can not use the *Select > Shrink...* tool, as this will only change the dimensions of the selection but not selected area.

To scale a selected image area we can do the following:

1. Select area to scale.
2. Create a "floating selection" with *Select > Float* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
3. Select the floating selection.
4. Choose the scale tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) to open below dialog from where you can scale by pixel dimensions, metric size, or percentage.
   .
   [image]

Comment: I can do the scale procedure but it's not working in this case. It doesn't have the right effect. The areas come in the wrong places if I scale to 97 % for instance.

Comment: You may have to scale them one by the other and then also move them accordingly (or use the alignment tool which also allows for an offset). You may get better options for such operations on using a vector graphics application (e.g. Inkscape).

Comment: In GIMP 2.10, the scale tool is located under Unified Transform in the Toolbox and uses shortcut Shift+S.

Comment: @qwr: thanks for the notice. I edited the answer for the appropriate shortcut to the scale tool.

Comment: Are you using windows 98 or something? lol

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be as follows:

- with the selection you have, toggle quick mask mode
- run the Erode filter as many times as necessary on that mask

You'll notice that the clear, selected parts of the mask will become smaller.

- finally, toggle quick mask mode again to switch back to the selection

You can now either invert the selection and cut the selected parts from the image, or keep the selection as is, create a new layer and fill the selection there.